# To align Face center with the nearby faces of an object in Blender 2.93.1

Tags: modeling, faces, normals, geometry

While modeling, the face center of certain faces got misaligned. It disables loop cut through all the faces that were selected. All the faces are rectangles. You can view it here:[image: The loop cut image]

I tried to reset by selecting all faces and Mesh> Normals> Reset Vectors

Also tried using Shift + N to Recalculate Outside. The face center of two faces are not in alignment with the neighboring faces.[image: Face center image]

Even turned on Face Orientation to check whether faces have any issues. [image]

Kindly suggest a way to re-align the face center with neighboring faces, so that loop cut can be done seamlessly.

Comment: The face center is automatically computed with the geometric barycenter of all its vertices. For a planar quad it is easy to compute, it's the intersection of both its diagonals. However, with polygons > 4 vertices the face center can be far from the 'expected' face center. It can even be outside of the face perimeter if the polygon is concave. The 2 culprit faces are n-gons, because of the vertex you added on top

Comment: I created a bevel for the face above it. So the one above it is not a n-gon.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Lemme try that out.

Comment: You can make them quads like that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObFM9.png

Comment: @Bipin What do you mean you created a bevel so it is not an n-gon? Edges of n-gons can be beveled, too. Instead of showing a screenshot in face select mode, make one in vertex select mode... than it should be easy to see if there are n-gons.

Comment: Just to be clear : your problem has nothing to do with face normals or face center alignment : The loop cut feature simply doesn't work when it has to cross an N-Gon because it doesn't know where to go to continue the loop

Comment: GordonBrinkmann @Gorgious, you guys were right. I created an N-Gon. And that was the root cause of all the issues.